# How to solve this error of function pointer?

Tags: c++

In a program a pointer is declared to function (p) which initialized to function (add)

i tried to read all the concepts related to function pointer.
But i couldn't solve it 
Please help me to solve this program with out any errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int n1, int n2) 
{
    return n1 + n2;
}

int *functocall(int,int);
int caller(int n1, int n2, int(*functocall)(int, int))
{
    return (*functocall)(n1, n2);
}

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> b >> c;

    int (*p)(int,int)=&add;
    a=caller(b,c,(*functocall)(b,c));
    printf("%d",a);

    return 0;
}
```

If the input is 20 70
Output must be 90

Comment: This function pointer is not even used anyhow.

Comment: @VTT can you please mention which function pointer is not even used..???

Comment: `In a program a pointer is declared to function (p) which initialized to function (add)`

Comment: `int (*p)(int, int)` is the declaration of a pointer `p` which points to a function returning `int` and taking two arguments of type `int`. (It has to be read from out to inside.) To use the pointer, just note `p`. To call the pointee, use `p(b, c)` or `(*p)(b, c)`. In C++, a function call is just an `operator()` which might be applied to a function pointer (or a function identifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*functocall)(b,c)` doesn't do what you expect, you're trying to call on the `functocall`. (Note that `functocall` is declared as a function, which takes two `int`s and returns a `int*`.)

You should pass the function pointer itself to `caller`, e.g.

```
a = caller(b, c, p);
```

or

```
a = caller(b, c, &add);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jMKVwkoAojiUBPsJ)

Comment: i didnt understood why  (*functocall)(b,c)  didnt work..?

Comment: @AlexStacy `caller` expects a function pointer as its 3rd parameter, then it could call on it inside the function body. But `(*functocall)(b,c)` is not a function pointer, it's a function-call expression.

Answer (score 1):

Way too complicated. it's often the case when you don't understand something you make it more complicated then it needs to be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int n1, int n2) 
{
    return n1 + n2;
}

int caller(int n1, int n2, int(*functocall)(int, int))
{
    return (*functocall)(n1, n2);
}

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> b >> c;

    a = caller(b,c,add);
    printf("%d",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Not too sure if you really need `caller`. Maybe you added than when you were trying to get it to work, but maybe not. An even simpler aternative is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int n1, int n2) 
{
    return n1 + n2;
}

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> b >> c;

    int (*functocall)(int, int) = add;
    a = functocall(b,c);
    printf("%d",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can u please explain whats the role of functocall  in my program?